# How does dropTA work?

Tags: r, quantmod

Here is what I typed along with the responses:

```
> barChart(SBGL)
> addSMA(n=50)
> dropTA(SMA)
Error in ta[cta] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> dropTA(addSMA)
Error in ta[cta] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Is it me or is the quantmod documentation rather sparse?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `dropTA` should be a character string, not the actual function itself.

```
dropTA("SMA")
dropTA("addSMA")
```